# Authentification failed when using SentinelHub Plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, sentinel, sentinel-hub

I downloaded SentinelHub v2 plugin into QGIS 3.14.

[image]

When I want to log in with my ID (from SentinelHub / Configuration Utility / ID) it says *"Authentification failed, check your credentials"*.
What can I do with it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error at the bottom says it all, and would suggest you check that you have correct client_id and client_secret copied from your "User settings" page in the dashboard (https://apps.sentinel-hub.com/dashboard).

The client_id is the "ID" of the selected OAuth client, while the secret was only visible to you when you have created a new OAuth client (with 'CLIENT_CREDENTIALS' type of grant).

Hope you manage to resolve the issue, otherwise feel free to post the issue also on our forum (https://forum.sentinel-hub.com)

Comment: I get it now...I followed steps for older version. Thank you.